# How to run a single function in an Elixir application?

Tags: elixir

I need create the equivalent of a `main` function for my project. I need add some dependencies to the project and use them to run a single function. I really don't need an OTP app so I think do define it like that (with supervisor and everything) would be an overkill.

I did a test and put it in the `mix.ex` like this and it works:

```
def application do
  MyModule.main

  [applications: [:logger]]
end
```

But feels unnatural. Is there a more standard way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

Putting it inside `application` only works the first time it compiles for some reason.

Comment: You may just use `elixir myscript.ex`, no mix in the mix :)

Answer (score 7):

Add a `mod` option to your mix.exs `application` function:

```
def application do
  [
    mod: {MyModule, []}, 
    applications: [:logger]]
    ...
  ]
end
```

And then you implement the Application behavior in that module:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    IO.puts "starting"
    # some more stuff
  end
end
```

Instead of the `main` function you specified in your example, I would use the `start` function as it is the accepted practice.  However, if you must use the `main` function, I am sure there is a way to override it.  Just look at the `Application` behavior's docs.

Comment: small typo, extra closing square braket in `[:logger]]`, should be `[:logger]`. Can't make the edit myself, SO is refusing it.

Comment: The last expression on your `start(_type, _args)` function should return a supervision tree. Something like this: `Supervisor.start_link([], strategy: :one_for_one)`, otherwise you'll see an error when executing your app.

Answer (score 1):

I like Jason's answer but before he responded I asked on slack and came to this answer:

Just create a module anywhere on your project (this on is on the lib folder) that is nested under `Mix.Tasks`

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.MyTask do
  def run(args) do
    #Do some stuff once
  end
end
```

And run it outside from the command line like this `mix my_task`. The nice thing is that you can pass optional args.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the escript functionality, although that also builds a stand alone script that runs "main". See

http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/mix/Mix.Tasks.Escript.Build.html

There's a simple hello world example at

https://github.com/bbense/elixir_cli_talk

Slides: http://bbense.github.io/elixir_cli_talk/

Comment: escript has annoying limits, for instance it does not work if you use modules that depend on compiled code coming from other languages.